# Center a span tag inside a fixed width div

Tags: css

Trying to center a `span` inside a div using `Margin:0 auto` but it seems not to work. I dont know why, `display:inline-block` will decrease to the width of text but i cant still use `margin:0 auto`.

```
<div>
<span>Updates</span>
</div>

div{
width:1000px;
height:200px;
background:red;
margin:0 auto;
}
div > span{
display:inline-block;
background:blue;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto;` will work only for `block` elements.

For `inline-block`, set the wrapping `<div>` to have `text-align: center;`.